# fast refresh Materialized view with primary key based log

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables

**car_acc** with primary key *car_acc_id*

and

**final_cost** with primary key *car_acc_id* references the previous one.

I have create 2 logs as:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON car_acc WITH PRIMARY KEY; 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON final_cost WITH PRIMARY KEY ;
```

I choose PrimaryKey log to solve import/export problems with ROW ID

then I've  tried to create MATERIALIZED view on these tables as:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW costs
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON demand
AS SELECT ca.car_id, ca.acc_id,f.cost
  FROM car_acc ca,final_cost f
  WHERE ca.car_acc_id=f.car_acc_id;
```

but with exception :

```
"cannot fast refresh materialized view %s.%s"
*Cause:    Either ROWIDs of certain tables were missing in the definition or
       the inner table of an outer join did not have UNIQUE constraints on
       join columns.
```

Comment: when are you exporting/importing?  How often? What replication approach are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You are close (and the exception does document the problem).  With the 11g documentation on join materialized views with no aggregates in the section,[Materialized Views Containing Only Joins](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm#i1006674),   you need to have a materialized view log with the rowid included.

Thus I would drop the existing materialized view logs and create the following materialized view logs as follows:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON car_acc
WITH ROWID;


CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON final_cost
WITH ROWID;
```

Also (per the aforementioned link above), you will need to add the rowid in the select statement of the materialized view as follows:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW costs
BUILD IMMEDIATE
REFRESH FAST ON demand
AS SELECT 
ca.rowid car_rid, f.rowid f_rowid,
ca.car_id, ca.acc_id,f.cost
  FROM car_acc ca,final_cost f
  WHERE ca.car_acc_id=f.car_acc_id;
```

Comment: as I said ,I want to use primary key ,not the RowID beacuse when i do import/export ,the rowId changes .So i want to build the log on the primary key